# Correlation coefficient of derived variables $U$ and $V$ based on sampling with replacement

Tags: probability, self-study, sampling, covariance

Consider a population of individuals of varying values. Suppose that 3 individuals are drawn
at random and with replacement from this population. Let X, Y , and Z be the values of the
individuals drawn respectively.
Consider the two derived variables $U = 2X+3Y$ and $V = 3X+2Y −3Z$. **Obtain the correlation
coefficient between U and V . Your answer should be a number**

Using Algebra of covariance and assuming $ x, y, z$ independent this is my result:
$\frac{6\ Var\ (x)+6\ var\ (y)}{\sqrt{(4\ Var(x)+9\ Var(y))(9\ Var(x) + 4\ Var(Y) - 9\ Var(z))}}$

my answer is not number, I dont know how to make it to a number.

Comment: Whatever came as your result, show your attempt here. Also, please frame a title that articulates the query in hand.

Comment: already added it

Comment: Thanks for the prompt action.